# Set column widths on multiple rows on PDF form created in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have a pdf doc created with asp.net. The pdf doc has a table on it but the problem is that the first row on the table has 7 columns the second row has 6 columns, also I need the columns' width in row 2 to be different than the columns' width in row 1. I can't use column span because the columns won't match the width I need them to be.
How can I make the cols in row 2 different widths than the cols in row 1?
Is there a way to make this happen?

Thank you

Comment: So - how are you creating this PDF ? Do you have any code as an example ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out. I just added a new table. So instead of having one table now I have 2 tables.
Thanks